# Is there a standard way to write row-wise median in matrix notation?

Tags: matrix, median, notation

**The background:**

I have estimated N time series models, each having the same coefficients.

From each of the models i have a column vector of the coefficients:

$(\alpha_{i,0},\alpha_{i,1},\alpha_{i,2},\alpha_{i,3})^T$

I store these into a matrix such as:

$\Omega = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{1,0} & ... & \alpha_{N,0}\\... & ... & ...\\ \alpha_{1,3} & ... & \alpha_{N,3}\end{bmatrix}$

Now, if i want to calculate row-wise mean, i could have something like:

$\overline{\Omega} = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{1,0} & ... & \alpha_{N,0}\\... & ... & ...\\ \alpha_{1,3} & ... & \alpha_{N,3}\end{bmatrix} * \boldsymbol{1}^T/N$

That seems like a pretty decent notation anyone can understand (I figure i could just write in words that i calculate a row-wise mean and be done with it...).

**The question:**

Is there a common approach in mathematics or statistics how to denote a calculation of row-wise median?

Or perhaps slightly different question: can i calculate row-wise median using matrix algebra?

Answer (score 4):

As median is a non-linear operation, I doubt there will be a way to express the row-wise median using matrix algebra. I have also never seen specific notation for that, so you will just have to define notation yourself.